# Simple Form does not work

Tags: php

Trying to make a simple form to send an email to a database.  New to php. The isset doesn't trigger so i guess the post isn't posting?!  Heres what i have tried.  I have tried with the get/post require etc.  Thanks for any help.

```
   <form class='form-horizontal' action='includes/news-letter.php' method='POST'>


                <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2'>
                <label for='' class='control-label'>Email</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control input-newsletter' name='newsletterEmail' id='inputPassword' placeholder='someone@somwhere.com'>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                <div class='col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-4'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-newsletter' name='newsletterEmail'>Get News Letter</button>
                </div>
                </div>

                </form>



   <?php 

    require_once("dbConnection.php");

    news_letter();

function news_letter(){



        // if(isset($_POST["newsletterEmail"]))
        if (isset($_POST["newsletterEmail"]) &&       !empty($_POST["newsletterEmail"])){

            // print_r($_POST);
             echo "IS SET";



            $newsletterEmail = $_POST['newsletterEmail']; 

            echo $newsletterEmail;

        if ($newsletterEmail==''){

            echo "<h6 class='alert alert-danger'>Please fill in field.</h6><br>";

        }else{

            $query = "INSERT INTO newsletterEmail ";
            $query .= "(newsletterEmail)";
            $query .= "VALUES (:newsletterEmail)";

            $ps = $db->prepare($query);

            $ps->execute(array(

                "newsletterEmail" => $newsletterEmail,

            ));




        }

    }
}; 


?>
```

Comment: you have duplicate name attributes, for one thing

Comment: Change your submit button name

Comment: that fixed it..thank you

Comment: Sorry about the lame-ness of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your submit button has the same name that your textfield, that why it doesn't work.

You don't have to check either "isset" and "!empty" (not empty) in fact if the value is set it's not empty so just do this :

```
if(!empty($_POST["newsletterEmail"])){ 
    echo "IS SET";
}
```